# Red5 server installation incomplete source code

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, red5

I currently working on red5 application where I need to create client server applications for live streaming.

I seen tutorials shown on http://red5.org (official site) and http://red5guide.com/ as shown on these videos I added all required softwares and plugin like Apache Ant, Ivy, Subclipse.

As shown on videos I downloaded source code of red5 server using svn link shown on official website https://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ using tortoise software.

But problem came when I checked the source code it is incomplete (build.xml file missing).

Original structure shown in video,
[image]

And the one which I have downloaded is,

[image]

When I downloaded files from SVN the downloading is completed successfully.

[image]

I also tried to import it from my eclipse using import using SVN.

So any one face this problem. Please help me in this problem.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any project that has been around for 8+ years changes and evolves; the information you've found is out-of-date and you will find updated projects for Red5 here: https://github.com/Red5
For the server itself, go here: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server

Ant and Ivy have not been used with the server portion of the project for several years now and what you will need to know now to proceed with the latest stuff is Maven.

Comment: Thank You @Mondain I considered that files are not completely downloaded on my side from svn due to which missing of files.So where can I get tutorials or documentation for integration and running of maven based server-client application.

Comment: The maven build info is on the front page of the red5-server repo